# How to remove some elements in a list in a dictionnary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

so I use Pyhton to compile tests data. I have about 15 lists of 14000 elements each. I've made a def whith all the calculus in it and I return a dictionnary with all the managed lists ready to be printed.

What I want to do is remove the n first element of each list in my dictionnary.
n is variable so I used this code to find the index of n.

```
for i in data['Force']:
    if data['Force'][i]<0:
        idx=bisect.bisect(data['Force'],0)
```

Can you help me out removing the n elements of all lists ?

Comment: Please give an example of the input and output you want.

Comment: You can use `list.pop` to remove elements from (either end of) a list, but `collections.deque` will be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
# d is the dictionary with lists
for lst in d.values():
    del lst[:n]
```

Comment: if you think the answer solved your problem, you can accept it by clicking on the grayish tick left next to the answer